# Random reboots after screen replacement of Nexus 5, twice

Tags: nexus-5, screen, boot-loop, reboot

I need your help, please.

Last year I broke my Nexus 5 screen.
After replacing the LCD (original) I encountered random reboots every day.
I took it back to the store, they replaced the screen again and the random reboots disappeared.

About a year later, 2 weeks ago, I broke the screen again :)
Took it to a different store and paid again for the original LCD replacement.
**Surprisingly, random reboots are back!**
My phone randomly reboots itself maybe 3-4 times a day, sometimes it won't turn on until I press the power button for about 10 seconds, and then it starts "optimizing apps" for a few minutes.

I tried clearing the cache, reinstalling kernels, factory reset, wiped everything and reverted to a blank new ROM, problem persists.
I also tried tapping the device, playing with the power button etc... nothing, it doesn't seem to be related.

I went back to the store, but I couldn't even show the problem, as the reboots only happen randomally and there's no way to initiate it.
He didn't agree to replace the screen again, and advised me to buy a new battery (which I didn't)

The technician seems like a nice guy, I don't think he is trying to rip me off.
He is the store owner so replacing the screen will go straight from his pocket, and he's really convinced that the random reboots has anything to do with the screen replacement.

On the other hand, the alternative is me paying again for a screen replacement, which I really don't want to, as paying for two screen replacement is almost like buying a new phone :/

My questions are:
1. How is it possible that the same problem happened twice? Maybe there is something wrong with my phone that is not related to the screen?
2. Any ideas how can I reproduce the reboots manually? so at least I can make him believe that there is a problem.
3. What do you think I should do? I really need a working phone and not excited about paying again.

Thank you!

Comment: Thank @Huey, I tried that already. No change.

Comment: Could it not really be a battery issue?

Comment: Maybe. But I find it hard to believe that a battery issue popped right when I changed the screen... what do you think?

Comment: Considering you've done every reset possible and installed multiple new roms and kernels I'd say you've exhausted all software avenues.

Comment: I agree. Therefore I'm convinced it's a faulty hardware, I just don't know how to prove it to get a new screen without paying again.

Answer (score 0):

I would say its hardware related. Also that the power supplied to the screen is randomly shorting which is causing the shut downs. I would open the unit and check all the plugs for the screen and the digitizer (aka touch ) and I would bet there is a bent (very slightly) pin on eather the male or female side. I'm a repair tech, and a nice guy, you said the last guy was too, if you ask nice he will probably open it and check for free or close to it. Intermitant problems can be very difficult to track down sometimes.   But that's where I would look first.